# How to approach writing a daemon to log user in

Tags: swift, macos, daemon

I am researching into writing a daemon that can process a request to log a user in. I am looking at

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/signing-a-daemon-with-a-restricted-entitlement

which explain, well, the difference between user agent and daemon and show an example how to create a daemon.

I need to launch a daemon to log a user into his account on `launchd` receiving a request to do so.

1. Does anyone have any pointers how to tap into the system's low level API to do that?
2. Are there any security concerns?

Comment: The whole notion sounds like it would be a massive security issue (if it were possible, which I hope it is not).

Comment: @matt Are you familiar with HYPR? Their daemon is capable of doing that.

Comment: I'm not. But I'm not feeling any safer. :)

Comment: @matt It's for controlled environment, not for public use.

Comment: I know, but now I'm feeling controlled. :)))))